# Show the user "buy now" or "edit gig" or "download button" in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, model-view-controller, model

This is the code i currently have

```
<% if user_signed_in? && @gig.user == current_user %>
<%= link_to "Edit your gig", edit_gig_path %>
<% else %>
  <%= link_to "Get this gig for #{@gig.pointsneeded} points", download_path(@gig)%>
<% end %>
```

The first line says **if** the user is singed in and the gig is owned by the current user Show **"Edit your gig"**,
Or **else** if the gig is not owned by the user,show him **"Get this gig for (a number) of points"**.

This is the models relationship i have

For **Purchase.rb**

```
class Purchase < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :gig
  belongs_to :buyer, class_name: 'User'
  belongs_to :seller, class_name: 'User'
end
```

For **User.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :purchases, foreign_key: 'buyer_id'
  has_many :gigs, through: :purchases, source: :buyer
  has_many :gigs
  has_many :sales, foreign_key: 'seller_id', class_name: 'Purchase'
end
```

For **Gig.rb**

```
class Gig < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :purchases
  has_many :buyers, through: :purchases
  has_many :sellers, through: :purchases
  belongs_to :user
end
```

> **Question:** How to make the logic so that,**if** the user owns the gig show "Edit your gig",**elsif** if the user purchased the the gig
>   from another user and it's in his `current_user.purchases` list,show
>   "you already purchased this gig",**else** "buy for 20 points".

**Full solution:**

```
<% if user_signed_in? && @gig.user == current_user %>
  <%= link_to "Edit your box", edit_gig_path%>
<% elsif @gig.buyers.pluck(:id).include?(current_user.id) %>
  <%= link_to "you already purchased this gig", edit_gig_path%>
<% else %>
  <%= link_to "Get this box for #{@gig.pointsneeded} points", download_picture_path(@gig)%>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, change this so that @gig doesn't make a sql call to load the user, but instead compares the gig's user_id:

```
<% if user_signed_in? && @gig.user_id == current_user %>
```

Comparing id's instead of the actual objects will make this page faster.

For checking to see if the current_user has bought the gig, do:

```
<% if @gig.buyers.pluck(:id).include?(current_user.id) %>
```

Comment: when calling buyer_id i get a undefined method "buyer_id" the same thing for `@gig.user_id` , it does't find the `_id `

Comment: Ah sorry. I updated my answer. If a gig belongs to a user, then you should have a user_id column on your gig table which would fix the @gig.user_id issue.

Comment: It worked thank you.,tough i had to use just @gig.user instead of @gig.user_id,look into my final solution to see the full code,i had to use.For some reason when i use `_id ` in the first line with @gig.user_id,than the  **if** statement doesn't work,just the **elsif and else**  code works.Anyway i got everything i wanted.Thank you.